# Odoo 10 missing Form view button as view_mode although it is

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, formview

It's very strange problem. I dowloaded "Contacts Directory" app on Odoo v9 and on Odoo v10. On v9 in the lower corner of the top I can see three different **view_modes**:

```
Kanban, List and Form.
```

[image]

On v10 in the lower corner of the top I can see only two different **view_modes**:

```
Kanban and List.
```

[image]

**On v10 there are no Form view button** and I have no idea why. I checked v9 and v10 Odoo source code for these views and there I can't find any differences.
On Odoo 10 I can reach Form view on "Contacts Directory" app only when I click on "Create" button but I need Form button together with Kanban and List view buttons.
On v10 the same problem with Form view seems with ir.translations and other models.I can't see `Form view button` as `view_mode`. I have no idea what can be wrong.

Do I need any apps to install or it's normal view_mode without Form view button on Odoo v10?

**UPDATED**

I asked this question on Odoo community and got the answer this an intended feature in v10 (not to show form view in the view switcher at the top right corner like it was on v9).

Comment: What you want to achieve and what you had done so far please insert that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. This button just opens the form view, which can be done by clicking the kanban card, or the tree row. (Maybe it was removed in v10 because it is redundant).